How to generate command to Insert multiple rows on duplicate key with null check before updating on mybatis
I'm using mybatis and creating a mapper on xml format.
I have a command to insert multiple values and overwrite (update) row, if it's already persisted.
For general command, it will be like this:
<insert id="batchUpsert" keyProperty="id" keyColumn="id" parameterType="com.mycompany.entity.PackageDO">

            INSERT INTO
            pkg_table
            (col1, col2, col3)
            VALUES
            <foreach item="item" collection="entities" separator=",">
            (
                #{item.col1},
                #{item.col2},
                #{item.col3}
            )
            </foreach>
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                `col1`= VALUES(col1),
                `col2`= VALUES(col2),
                `col3`= VALUES(col3)
    </insert>

But this will overwrite column by the null value, if col1, col2, col3 is null, which is not what I want.
So how do I add a check similar like:
<if test = "item.col1 != null"> `col1`= VALUES(col1), </if>

into the part ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE because it's outside of <foreach>
this one does not work:
<insert id="batchUpsert" keyProperty="id" keyColumn="id" parameterType="com.mycompany.entity.PackageDO">

            INSERT INTO
            pkg_table
            (col1, col2, col3)
            VALUES
            <foreach item="item" collection="entities" separator=",">
            (
                #{item.col1},
                #{item.col2},
                #{item.col3}
            )
            </foreach>
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                <if test = "item.col1 != null"> `col1`= VALUES(col1), </if>
                <if test = "item.col2 != null"> `col1`= VALUES(col2), </if>
                <if test = "item.col3 != null"> `col1`= VALUES(col3) </if>
    </insert>

I can not move ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE inside the <foreach>, because system does not accept multiple statement.

You can write ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = coalesce(values(col1), col1), col2 = coalesce(.... FYI, values() is deprecated. Also, this may be off-topic, but you won't be able to get the generated keys for each row with this approach (see this thread).

@ave i tried but mysql say: do not support coalesce(VALUES(gmt_process_time), gmt_process_time), insert on duplicate key updatestatement only support 'primitive value' and values()

Which version do you use? I tested it with MySQL 8.3.0 + mysql-connector-java 8.0.30. Also, what's the error code? And gmt_process_time  is not in your example. Is that some kind of "special" column? Please update your question.

hi @ave , that column is col1, my bad. im using mysql ver5.3. may be it does not support that syntax

I guess 5.3 is a little bit too old  The syntax seems to be working on 5.5 which is the oldest version DB Fiddle supports https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/33s9n9pEA8YDXaJMzrPRrL/0
